# WiX 3.8 WPF app doesn't load on .NET 4.5.1 Windows 8.1 64-Bit machine

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, wix

I have a WPF application that works fine in debug mode in Visual Studio 2013.

I have a WIX 3.8 installer, which compiles and runs. Installing as expected to C:\Program Files\StackedBrowsersConfig64Bit on my 64-bit Windows 8.1 machine.

However, When I try to launch the application from the shortcut I had the installer place on the desktop the application does not load.  When I try to launch the application exe directly from the installed location application does not load.

I've tried everything I can think of by way of project configuration, x64, Any CPU. Does not make any difference, it refuses to load.

What on earth is going on?

My installer is made of 3 files:

Config.wxi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
    <!-- Product name as you want it to appear in Add/Remove Programs-->
    <?define Company = "Oakton" ?>
    <?define HomeDirectory = "STACKEDBROWSERS_HOME" ?>
    <?define UpgradeCode = "E9FAF2A9-157E-413C-A3B2-1F42E141BC75" ?>
    <?define Version = "1.0.0.0" ?>
    <?define Edition = "Standard" ?>
    <?define KeyName = "ActivationCode" ?>
    <?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
        <?define Win64 = "yes" ?>
        <?define ProductName = "StackedBrowsersConfig64Bit" ?>
        <?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFiles64Folder" ?>        
    <?else ?>
        <?define Win64 = "no" ?>
        <?define ProductName = "StackedBrowsersConfig" ?>
        <?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFilesFolder" ?>
    <?endif ?>
</Include>
```

Bundle.wxs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
<?include $(var.StackedBrowsers.SetupLibrary.ProjectDir)\Config.wxi?>
  <Bundle Name="StackedBrowsers Config"
          SplashScreenSourceFile="Splash/Splash.bmp"
          IconSourceFile="Icons/splash128x128.ico"
          Version="$(var.Version)"
          Manufacturer="$(var.Company)"
          Copyright="Copyright © 2013 - 2014 Full Circle Solutions. All Rights Reserved."
          UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
      <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="Licences\eula.rtf" LogoFile="Logos\Oakton.png" SuppressOptionsUI="yes"/>
      </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
      <Chain>
          <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.StackedBrowsers.Standard.Setup.Msi.TargetPath)" />
      </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Product.wxs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:fx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
    <?include $(var.StackedBrowsers.SetupLibrary.ProjectDir)\Config.wxi?>
        <Product Id="*"
                 Name="$(var.ProductName)"
                 Language="1033"
                 Version="$(var.Version)"
                 Manufacturer="$(var.Company)"
                 UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
            <Package Keywords="Installer"
                     Description="$(var.ProductName) $(var.Version) Installer"
                     InstallerVersion="500"
                     Compressed="yes"
                     InstallScope="perMachine"
                     Platform="x64"/>
            <!--<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of $(var.ProductName) is already installed." />-->
                <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
                <!-- Check .NET 4.5 is installed -->
                <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>
                <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.5. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
                    <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
                </Condition>
<!--Uninstall old versions-->
<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.0.0" 
                  IncludeMinimum="yes"
                  OnlyDetect="no"
                  Maximum="$(var.Version)" 
                  IncludeMaximum="no"
                  Property="PREVIOUSFOUND" />
</Upgrade>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<!-- Program Installation -->
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <!--Add EventSource-->
  <Component Id="StackedBrowserConfigEventSource" Guid="79B9F044-231B-429B-9E8B-0C86255B2494">
    <util:EventSource Name="$(var.ProductName)"
                      Log="Application"
                      EventMessageFile="[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]EventLogMessages.dll"
                      KeyPath='yes'/>
  </Component>
  <!-- Define the directory structure -->
  <Directory Id="$(var.PlatformProgramFilesFolder)">
    <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
      <Component Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Guid="86E26457-AB9F-4F73-9987-71267183DA78" Feature="Complete"
                 SharedDllRefCount="no" KeyPath="yes" NeverOverwrite="no" Permanent="no" Transitive="no"
                 Win64="yes" Location="either">
        <CreateFolder>
          <util:PermissionEx User="Everyone"
                             Read="yes"
                             GenericAll="yes"
                             Delete="yes"
                             CreateChild="yes"
                             CreateFile="yes"
                             DeleteChild="yes"
                             Traverse="yes"/>
        </CreateFolder>
      </Component>
      <Directory Id="ImagesDIR" Name="Images">
        <Component Id="AddFile" Guid="94CF00DD-52FE-423C-BCFC-5AAE4A4A4AC1">
          <File Id='AddPNG' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Images\add.png' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
        </Component>
        <Component Id="DeleteFile" Guid="B4C9DCB3-1A97-449F-B714-62E472236C76">
          <File Id='DeletePNG' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Images\delete.png' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
        </Component>
        <Component Id="LogoFile" Guid="55F583CE-66C5-4C45-900E-50200EE3A34D">
          <File Id='LogoPNG' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Images\logo.png' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
        </Component>
        <Component Id="SaveFile" Guid="4C8DDD65-A12B-421D-B65E-7A050C5E84A0">
          <File Id='SavePNG' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Images\save.png' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
        </Component>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="MappingsDIR" Name="Mappings">
        <Directory Id="BrowserStackDIR" Name="BrowserStack">
          <Component Id="BSAvailableDesktopPlatformsFile" Guid="292D1AED-6F82-47C8-96CB-4AD03876EF18">
            <File Id='BSAvailableDesktopPlatformsJSON' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Mappings\BrowserStack\availabledesktopplatforms.json' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="BSAvailableMobilePlatformsFile" Guid="A28062C9-03AB-4E10-8FC9-B7E173630A55">
            <File Id='BSAvailableMobilePlatformsJSON' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Mappings\BrowserStack\availablemobileplatforms.json' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
        <Directory Id="SauceLabsDIR" Name="SauceLabs">
          <Component Id="SLAvailableDesktopPlatformsFile" Guid="93D07BB6-3BD8-4F73-9FFA-3A97C09E479F">
            <File Id='SLAvailableDesktopPlatformsJSON' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Mappings\SauceLabs\availabledesktopplatforms.json' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="SLAvailableMobilePlatformsFile" Guid="BCCC11D9-1A21-45FA-AF50-52A668CE10E9">
            <File Id='SLAvailableMobilePlatformsJSON' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Mappings\SauceLabs\availablemobileplatforms.json' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Component Id="AutomatedTestingCommon" Guid="3B77E40A-4723-40E8-844E-7320F1431B7D">
        <File Id='AutomatedTestingCommonDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)AutomatedTestingCommon.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="BrowserStackGallioMbUnit" Guid="9B111E0B-2969-47FB-8E85-023106358C89">
        <File Id='BrowserStackGallioMbUnitDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)BrowserStack-GallioMbUnit.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="BrowserStackNUnit" Guid="157316C5-D578-489A-93A2-0056088E3D1B">
        <File Id='BrowserStackNUnitDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)BrowserStack-NUnit.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="BrowserStackTunnelJAR" Guid="8CAEB4F9-DCBF-48D5-B27F-CCC69D9A185E">
        <File Id='BrowserStackTunnel.JAR' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)BrowserStackTunnel.jar' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="FirstFloor.ModernUI" Guid="21B50C54-ADD9-47D5-A8C3-B379AC569085">
        <File Id='FirstFloor.ModernUIDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)FirstFloor.ModernUI.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="FirstFloor.ModernUIXMLFile" Guid="3F1DDC50-3F9B-4A33-8DF4-E73CCED3C990">
        <File Id='FirstFloor.ModernUIXML' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)FirstFloor.ModernUI.xml' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Gallio" Guid="8377A734-5C3D-498B-9801-AE3C083D956D">
        <File Id='GallioDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Gallio.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Gallio40" Guid="FC47E3E2-6637-4243-85B7-4B9B6C11609E">
        <File Id='Gallio40DLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Gallio40.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="MbUnit" Guid="9B9A93C5-4D5B-4722-82ED-E4745295EC78">
        <File Id='MbUnitDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)MbUnit.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="MbUnit40" Guid="7F75FFF1-91F4-4461-B837-37C6FDEF52E0">
        <File Id='MbUnit40DLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)MbUnit40.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="NewtonsoftJsonDll" Guid="695C6E75-7D25-4A17-ACCC-68916223E11E">
        <File Id='NewtonsoftJsonDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Newtonsoft.Json.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="NewtonsoftJsonXMLFile" Guid="938CDC9B-68C7-4C45-9D06-B15526F779B5">
        <File Id='NewtonsoftJsonXML' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)Newtonsoft.Json.xml' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="NHamcrest" Guid="79698D11-C169-40E7-9464-4D646B2FE903">
        <File Id='NHamcrestDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)NHamcrest.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="nunit.core" Guid="6307E0F1-6447-4C53-8B08-59427E05043B">
        <File Id='nunit.coreDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)nunit.core.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="nunit.core.interfaces" Guid="30CF80CC-ED4C-427F-AB97-7644A92A8D80">
        <File Id='nunit.core.interfacesDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)nunit.core.interfaces.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="nunit.framework" Guid="95763583-74E9-4D16-909F-23C6CA586A16">
        <File Id='nunit.frameworkDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)nunit.framework.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="nunit.frameworkXMLFile" Guid="1F8F174B-1226-4EBF-8D16-CEB4290AA5CC">
        <File Id='nunit.frameworkXML' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)nunit.framework.xml' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="SauceLabsGallioMbUnit" Guid="487D6097-E053-451E-9DE2-5447438E32CE">
        <File Id='SauceLabsGallioMbUnitDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)SauceLabs-GallioMbUnit.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="SauceLabsNUnit" Guid="6CAA18A5-628E-4179-B2CE-405FE66F87C4">
        <File Id='SauceLabsNUnitDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)SauceLabs-NUnit.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="sc.exe" Guid="C534A94F-56F4-47AF-AFB6-90CC5F6EE678">
        <File Id='scEXE' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)sc.exe' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="SBCore" Guid="F9FEC582-A26E-4ED1-BB19-4C800DEB9D66">
        <File Id='StackedBrowserCoreDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)StackedBrowsers.Core.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="SBEXE" Guid="7D12BCD3-6D3B-43EB-833D-DD2015AA616D">
        <File Id='StackedBrowserWPFEXE' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)BrowserStacker.exe' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="WebDriver" Guid="636E9659-703B-434F-A749-1CB11FC0088D">
        <File Id='WebDriverDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)WebDriver.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="WebDriver.Support" Guid="FBC29578-B656-4993-8468-B01C91A63A84">
        <File Id='WebDriver.SupportDLL' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)WebDriver.Support.dll' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="WebDriver.SupportXMLFile" Guid="0531CE21-91E2-4248-97D5-068070E4392B">
        <File Id='WebDriver.SupportXML' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)WebDriver.Support.xml' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="WebDriverXMLFile" Guid="13B207DD-4996-47FC-B4B2-3E6064DA0CF9">
        <File Id='WebDriverXML' Source='$(var.BrowserStacker.TargetDir)WebDriver.xml' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="$(var.ProductName)"/>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
</Directory>
<!-- Add files to installer package -->
<DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY">
</DirectoryRef>

<!-- Add the shortcuts-->
<DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
  <Component Id="UninstallShortcut" Guid="F0E7ED75-D61F-4E71-90A3-7D34E43797B5">
    <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct"
              Name="Uninstall $(var.ProductName)"
              Description="Uninstalls $(var.ProductName)"
              Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe"
              Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"
              Icon="WebIcon"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\$(var.ProductName)" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
  <!---Create Environment variable-->
  <Component Id="PRODUCTHOMEENVVAR" Guid="EDDFF32A9ACC48A2ADF9FE9BEEFE8D19">
    <Environment Id="ProductHomeVar"
                 Action="set"
                 Part="all"
                 Name="$(var.HomeDirectory)"
                 Permanent="no"
                 System="yes"
                 Value="[APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY]" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\$(var.ProductName)" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
    <CreateFolder />
    <RemoveFolder Id="ProductHomeVar" On="uninstall"/>
  </Component>
  <!--Add PRODUCTHOMEENVVAR to Path-->
  <Component Id="PATHENVVAR" Guid="DA9660D3ABF94CE5BE36176DC5022623">
    <Environment Id="PathVar"
                 Action="set"
                 Part="first"
                 Name="Path"
                 Permanent="no"
                 System="yes"
                 Value="[APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY]" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\$(var.ProductName)" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
    <CreateFolder />
    <RemoveFolder Id="PathVar" On="uninstall"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
  <Component Id="DesktopShortcut" Guid="B4CC3C76E898458186E695F546521F57">
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut"
              Name="StackedBrowsers Config"
              Description="StackedBrowser Config Tool"
              Target="[APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY]BrowserStacker.exe"
              WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
                   Key="Software/$(var.ProductName)"
                   Name="installed"
                   Type="integer"
                   Value="1"
                   KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<!-- Tell WiX to install the files -->
<Feature Id="Complete" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
  <!--<ComponentRef Id="EULAPDF" />-->
  <ComponentRef Id="AddFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="BSAvailableDesktopPlatformsFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="BSAvailableMobilePlatformsFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="SLAvailableDesktopPlatformsFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="SLAvailableMobilePlatformsFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="DeleteFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="AutomatedTestingCommon"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="BrowserStackGallioMbUnit"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="BrowserStackNUnit"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="BrowserStackTunnelJAR"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="Gallio"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="Gallio40"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="MbUnit"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="MbUnit40"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="NHamcrest"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="nunit.core"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="nunit.core.interfaces"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="nunit.framework"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="nunit.frameworkXMLFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="SauceLabsGallioMbUnit"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="SauceLabsNUnit"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="sc.exe"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="WebDriver"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="WebDriver.Support"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="WebDriver.SupportXMLFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="WebDriverXMLFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="FirstFloor.ModernUI"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="FirstFloor.ModernUIXMLFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="LogoFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="NewtonsoftJsonDll"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="NewtonsoftJsonXMLFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="SaveFile"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="SBCore"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="SBEXE"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="UninstallShortcut"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="DesktopShortcut"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="PRODUCTHOMEENVVAR"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="PATHENVVAR"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="StackedBrowserConfigEventSource"/>
  <!--<ComponentRef Id="Manual"/>-->
</Feature>

        <!-- Step 4: Define icon -->
        <Icon Id="WebIcon" SourceFile="Icons\oakton128x128.ico" />
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Assistance much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any errors in the Application Event Log?  Is your app running unelevated and trying to write/create files in its directory?

Comment: Thanks Sean.  Good point.  a FileNotFound exception.  ProcessMon shows many NAME NOT FOUNDs on Registry Keys.  There were some PATH NOT FOUNDS on a heap of PDBs but strangly have gone away after I added one PDB to the installer. Issue persists. How do I find out which file was not found?